# Create Multidimentional Associative Array from Database

Tags: php, arrays, database, associative

I'm having a problem trying to make an associative array that would looked like :

```
Array(
      Array('111.01.0040' => 'PEMBENAHAN PIPA TURBIN'),
      Array('111.01.0041' => 'PENGELASAN UNVIL'),
      Array('111.01.0042' => 'BONGK.PASANG PINION/LAMAK SPIE')
      );
```

from a table that looked like

```
No    | kdbr        | nmbr
1     | 111.01.0040 | PEMBENAHAN PIPA TURBIN
2     | 111.01.0041 | PENGELASAN UVIL
3     | 111.01.0042 | BONGK.PASANG PINION/LAMAK SPIE
```

all i can do is having an array that looked like

```
Array ( [0] => Array (
    [111.01.0040] => PEMBENAHAN PIPA TURBIN
    [111.01.0041] => PENGELASAN UNVIL
    [111.01.0042] => BONGK.PASANG PINION/LAMAK SPIE);
```

and my code is like

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', '*****', '*****', '*****');
$query = "SELECT kdbr, nmbr FROM tb_master_barang";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$data_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_array[$row['kdbr']] = $row['nmbr'];
}
```

is it possible having array like what i want to make by getting data from database? can anyone help me?

thanks :)

Comment: `$data_array[] = array($row['kdbr'] => $row['nmbr']);`

Comment: one thing again to ask, in my table `kdbr` is defined as varchar, but at array it's out as `["111.01.0041"]` and not `"111.01.0041"`, how can i remove the `[]` tag?

Comment: When is what exactly output as `["..."]`?

Comment: i'm sorry, i was doing on a wrong path for a long time... what i need is creating an array that like `array(array('kdbr'=>"111.01.0041", nmbr => PENGELASAN UNVIL)` instead of what i write up there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but you have thought about it all backwards.

```
Array (
     Array(A => B)
     Array(C => D)
)
```

is actually

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(A => B)
    [1] => Array(C => D)
)
```

This means you have to create a new array each time if you want the `Array (x => y)` effect.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_array[$row['no']] = array($row['kdbr'] => $row['nmbr']);
}
```

or if you don't want it ordered by $row['no'] but instead just want it added to the array by the way you order your SQL-query:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_array[] = array($row['kdbr'] => $row['nmbr']);
}
```